# How to insert options in the gallery?

Tags: android, image-gallery, optionmenu

1. I am working on an Android project and I am now working on the gallery on which I have 
   created the display of images.
2. I want to insert the options like View ( Grid view etc.,) , Sending options , Move etc.,
   and I want the option menu at the bottom corner of the screen. If so how I should program.
   give me your suggestion and sample link also......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i am not gettin your question clearly but i hope you are looking for menus like Options and Exit etc on the bottom of ur screen, am i right?

for that u need to create menu like option for that menu u need to set what it should do in

onOptionItemSelcted...

for creating menu you can use this link : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html